# How to create OAuth2 Opaque(Reference) Access Tokens

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

How to create OAuth2 Opaque(Reference) Access Tokens in apimanager 410? I followed [enter link description here](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/3.1.0/learn/api-security/oauth2/access-token-types/opaque-tokens/#!), but cannot find OAUTH token type when we create applications.

I want to create this application because of the issue [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75214360/previous-token-is-revoked-when-token-endpoint-is-called-even-before-token-expiry/75224292?noredirect=1#comment132784588_75224292). if same token is sent every time we call the token api, this will work for us. Our tests need to get the token first and use it from there. there can be different apis calling in different times and this will expire the first token.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a lengthy manual method that lets you to create opaque tokens in APIM 4.1.0, but our recommendation is to proceed with the JWT token-based applications. This will reduce the load at the gateway with token validation which is a huge performance gain. Even if you used the same clientID, or secret Pair, you can change the scopes set with a [device scope](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/design/api-security/oauth2/oauth2-scopes/scope-whitelisting/) and I believe this should give you the ability to create multiple tokens at the same time.

Having said that, you can create opaque token in the below approach, but this will remove the user experience provided in the devportal and you have to use carbon console(https://localhost:9443/carbon) if you need to change your application.

1. log in to admin portal (https://localhost:9443/admin)
2. Open Key managers --> resident key manager (or whatever the key manager you have) --> and select `Out Of Band Provisioning` and save.
   [image]
3. Log in to carbon console (https://localhost:9443/carabon)
4. Register a service provider. [image]
5. Under Inbound authentication config, select OAuth/OpenID connect configurations and configure an OAuth Applicaiton[image]
6. Add you application details from here as you prefer with the listed grant types and create an application.
7. **Make sure to select the token issuer and default. This is where you select whether the token type is JWT or Opaque.** [image]
8. Once you save it, you can find the client ID secret pair in here. [image]
9. Log in to devportal (https://localhost:9443/devportal)
10. Create an application.
11. Under the production Keys section, now you can see a new option enabled as provide existing OAuth keys. [image]
12. Add the consumer key secret pair you created in the step 8.
13. Now you have created an application that generates opaque tokens.

Comment: Added same content as a StackOverflow article and added some more information on architecture and what we are doing here. https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/wso2/articles/75285199/how-to-create-an-application-that-generate-opaque-token-in-wso2-apim-manager-4-x

Comment: The device token approach worked. I will try the opaque token creation steps.